# Setting libgdx GestureDetector to limited area

Tags: input, libgdx, listener, gesture, gesturedetector

I've been trying to set my Gesture Detector to only react to the right half of the screen, because on the left side I have a touchpad. I use a multiplexer. I have looked everywhere but I can't find an answer. Please let me know what do I need to be able to limit my Gesture Detector to only the right side.

They work fine because everything is set to return false, but I want them to work at the same time. The fact that the left side (when I use the touchpad) is also responding to the fling action, prevents them from working at the same time.

Thank you for your time!